# Wifi not working in debian 8.9 having RTL8723de driver ([10ec:d723])

Tags: debian, wifi, network-interface, internet, realtek

Please help me to make my wifi working. I was working on this for last two weeks and tried many workarounds. Now I have freshly reinstalled Debian and ready to start from the beginning. Below are the details of system network.

```
01:00.0 Ethernet controller: Realtek Semiconductor Co., Ltd. RTL8111/8168/8411 PCI Express Gigabit Ethernet Controller (rev 15)
Subsystem: Hewlett-Packard Company Device 8328
Flags: bus master, fast devsel, latency 0, IRQ 141
I/O ports at 4000 [size=256]
Memory at b1104000 (64-bit, non-prefetchable) [size=4K]
Memory at b1100000 (64-bit, non-prefetchable) [size=16K]
Capabilities: [40] Power Management version 3
Capabilities: [50] MSI: Enable+ Count=1/1 Maskable- 64bit+
Capabilities: [70] Express Endpoint, MSI 01
Capabilities: [b0] MSI-X: Enable- Count=4 Masked-
Capabilities: [100] Advanced Error Reporting
Capabilities: [140] Virtual Channel
Capabilities: [160] Device Serial Number 01-00-00-00-68-4c-e0-00
Capabilities: [170] Latency Tolerance Reporting
Capabilities: [178] L1 PM Substates
Kernel driver in use: r8169

02:00.0 Network controller: Realtek Semiconductor Co., Ltd. Device d723
Subsystem: Hewlett-Packard Company Device 8319
Flags: bus master, fast devsel, latency 0, IRQ 11
I/O ports at 3000 [size=256]
Memory at b1000000 (64-bit, non-prefetchable) [size=64K]
Capabilities: [40] Power Management version 3
Capabilities: [50] MSI: Enable- Count=1/1 Maskable- 64bit+
Capabilities: [70] Express Endpoint, MSI 00
Capabilities: [100] Advanced Error Reporting
Capabilities: [148] Virtual Channel
Capabilities: [168] Device Serial Number 00-e0-4c-00-00-00-00-00
Capabilities: [178] Latency Tolerance Reporting
Capabilities: [180] L1 PM Substates
```

---

```
# iwconfig 
usb0      no wireless extensions.
lo        no wireless extensions.
eth0      no wireless extensions.
```

---

```
# iwlist scan
usb0      Interface doesn't support scanning
lo        Interface doesn't support scanning
eth0      Interface doesn't support scanning
```

---

```
# ip link
1: lo: <LOOPBACK,UP,LOWER_UP> mtu 65536 qdisc noqueue state UNKNOWN mode DEFAULT group default 
link/loopback 00:00:00:00:00:00 brd 00:00:00:00:00:00
2: eth0: <NO-CARRIER,BROADCAST,MULTICAST,UP> mtu 1500 qdisc pfifo_fast state DOWN mode DEFAULT group default qlen 1000
link/ether 18:60:24:11:f8:77 brd ff:ff:ff:ff:ff:ff
3: usb0: <BROADCAST,MULTICAST,UP,LOWER_UP> mtu 1500 qdisc pfifo_fast state UNKNOWN mode DEFAULT group default qlen 1000
link/ether fe:47:68:4a:9f:e3 brd ff:ff:ff:ff:ff:ff
```

---

```
# dmesg | grep 8168
[    0.372439] pci 0000:01:00.0: [10ec:8168] type 00 class 0x020000
[    0.949919] r8169 0000:01:00.0 eth0: RTL8168b/8111b at 0xffffc900006b4000, 18:60:24:11:f8:77, XID 14100800 IRQ 141
```

---

```
# dmesg | grep 8169
[    0.949289] r8169 Gigabit Ethernet driver 2.3LK-NAPI loaded
[    0.949299] r8169 0000:01:00.0: can't disable ASPM; OS doesn't have ASPM control
[    0.949443] r8169 0000:01:00.0 (unregistered net_device): unknown MAC, using family default
[    0.949679] r8169 0000:01:00.0: irq 141 for MSI/MSI-X
[    0.949919] r8169 0000:01:00.0 eth0: RTL8168b/8111b at 0xffffc900006b4000, 18:60:24:11:f8:77, XID 14100800 IRQ 141
[    0.949922] r8169 0000:01:00.0 eth0: jumbo features [frames: 4080 bytes, tx checksumming: ko]
[   15.868934] r8169 0000:01:00.0 eth0: link down
```

The output of `lspci -knn | grep Net -A2`:

```
02:00.0 Network controller [0280]: Realtek Semiconductor Co., Ltd. Device 
[10ec:d723] 
Subsystem: Hewlett-Packard Company Device [103c:8319]
```

Comment: Please provide more details about how you are managing your network connections. Are you using ifupdown (`/etc/network/interfaces`) or something else?

Comment: @Faheem Mitha `sss@mydebiansys:~$ cat /etc/network/interfaces`
`auto lo`
`iface lo inet loopback`

Comment: @GAD3R   
`sss@mydebiansys:~$ lspci -knn | grep Net -A2
02:00.0 Network controller [0280]: Realtek Semiconductor Co., Ltd. Device [10ec:d723]
 Subsystem: Hewlett-Packard Company Device [103c:8319]
`

Comment: @FaheemMitha
I have tried ifup eth0
but didn't worked

Comment: Add the contents of `/etc/network/interfaces` to the question, please. And it only contains the loopback network interface. Please clarify - are you using `ifupdown` or something else?

Comment: `apt install r8168-dkms`

Comment: @Confguy2016 's now probably deleted answer: Unofficial Linux driver here: https://github.com/smlinux/rtl8723de

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**Ethernet**

Edit your `/etc/network/interfaces` as follows:

```
# interfaces(5) file used by ifup(8) and ifdown(8)
# Include files from /etc/network/interfaces.d:
source-directory /etc/network/interfaces.d
    
auto lo
iface lo inet loopback
 
auto eth0
iface eth0 inet dhcp
```

To get the internet working through `eth0`:

```
ifdown eth0
ifup eth0
```

**Wifi**

**Update**

A working driver is available on [smlinux](https://github.com/smlinux/rtl8723de) repository ([see the comments](https://github.com/lwfinger/rtlwifi_new/issues/270))

**To install the `rtl8723de` driver  you should have a kernel version >=4.11.**

The easy way is to install Debian Stretch then upgrade your kernel version from backports (kernel  `4.13` is available)

To install the `rtl8723de` on Debian Jessie you should compile your kernel >4.11

the install process:

The driver can be installed as follow:

```
git clone https://github.com/smlinux/rtl8723de.git
cd rtl8723de
make
make install
```

> **Realtek RTL8723DE module for Linux kernel version 5:**

```
git clone https://github.com/smlinux/rtl8723de.git -b current
dkms add ./rtl8723de
dkms install rtl8723de/5.1.1.8_21285.20171026_COEX20170111-1414
depmod -a
reboot
```

**Update** debian 10

The driver is available on [lwfinger/rtw88](https://github.com/lwfinger/rtw88):

> Note:1) This code will build on any kernel 4.19 and newer as long as the distro has not modified any of the kernel APIs.

> 2. This repository includes drivers for the following cards:

> RTL8822BE, RTL8822CE, RTL8821CE, and RTL8723DE

```
sudo apt-get update
sudo apt-get install make gcc linux-headers-$(uname -r) build-essential git

git clone https://github.com/lwfinger/rtw88.git
cd rtw88
make
sudo make install

sudo modprobe -rv rtw_8723de 
sudo modprobe -v rtw_8723de
```

Comment: Thanks for the straight answer, however, i will wait. If you find any workarounds in future then please let me know.

Comment: Always do `ifdown eth0` before doing `ifup`. As far as I know `dhclient eth0` is not necessary. What is that for?

Comment: @gad3r  Many people suggest me to do apt install r8168-dkms. I have tried it but no positive output.  May i know the use of r8168? Is there any easily understandable links?

Comment: @Jith you need the `r8168-dkms` package for your ethernet card

Comment: @lwfinger awesome....... Thanks a lot for your update.

Answer (score 4):

Unofficial Linux driver here: https://github.com/smlinux/rtl8723de

Please note that, I am not the author or contributor to the above driver. I came to know about this project run by user "smlinux" while subscribed to lwfinger's rtlwifi-new git project page.

I have a HP 15-BS576TX laptop with RTL8727DE wireless module and this driver worked fine. Compiling it is simple; You may either clone the source using git or download the source as zip from the above link.

Then, open a terminal in the source directory (rtl8723de) and run below commands which will install 8723de.ko kernel module to the modules directory.

```
make
sudo make install && sync;
sudo modprobe 8723de
```

That's it. After few months of owning this laptop, finally Wifi worked! Though, community must be aware that, official accommodation of this driver or other driver for this module in Linux kernel may take time. Also, please look into https://github.com/lwfinger/rtlwifi_new for any updated driver available, which is provided by Realtek, the manufacture of the said WiFi module.

Comment: This guy explained a better way to install: https://askubuntu.com/a/988778/314168

Comment: I have tried everything but wifi still not working in my HP BS542TU laptop. First upgraded kernel to 4.11 and downloaded and installed the module. No idea why this is not showing up.  :(

Comment: @Jith : Can you open a terminal and run below commands:                          lspci |grep -i network and uname -r

Comment: Never mind wifi worked with kernel 4.14, hurray............