# drivers issue for Realtek RTL8723DE wlan on debian 10 with kernel 5.10

Tags: debian, wifi, drivers, realtek, wlan

I have recently installed Debian 10.9 with KDE. And tried to use WiFi and learned that my wlan is unclaimed by doing this:

```
neevan@nebian:~$ sudo lshw -C network
  *-network                 
       description: Ethernet interface
       product: RTL8111/8168/8411 PCI Express Gigabit Ethernet Controller
       vendor: Realtek Semiconductor Co., Ltd.
...
...
  *-network UNCLAIMED
       description: Network controller
       product: Realtek Semiconductor Co., Ltd.
       vendor: Realtek Semiconductor Co., Ltd.
       physical id: 0
       bus info: pci@0000:02:00.0
       version: 00
       width: 64 bits
       clock: 33MHz
       capabilities: pm msi pciexpress cap_list
       configuration: latency=0
       resources: ioport:3000(size=256) memory:b1000000-b100fff
```

### Here's what I have done to fix it:

1. `sudo apt install firmware-realtek` and restart didn't work
2. I have also installed lot of unofficial drivers from GitHub
3. I have followed every answer of [this question on unix & linux](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/394012/wifi-not-working-in-debian-8-9-having-rtl8723de-driver-10ecd723)
4. I have learned that my particular wlan device doesn't have drivers in kernel <= 4, so i enabled back ports(by adding `deb http://deb.debian.org/debian buster-backports main contrib non-free` to my "/etc/apt/sources.list") and upgraded my kernel to 5.10 and did `sudo apt update && sudo apt upgrade`, nothing happened then too.

After doing all the above, I could neither see WiFi on the bottom right panel nor could I see anything when did `nmcli dev wifi`.

### More information about my OS and device:

```
neevan@nebian:~$ uname -a
Linux nebian 5.10.0-0.bpo.4-amd64 #1 SMP Debian 5.10.19-1~bpo10+1 (2021-03-13) x86_64 GNU/Linux
neevan@nebian:~$ lspci -k
...
...
01:00.0 Ethernet controller: Realtek Semiconductor Co., Ltd. RTL8111/8168/8411 PCI Express Gigabit Ethernet Controller (rev 15)
        Subsystem: Hewlett-Packard Company RTL8111/8168/8411 PCI Express Gigabit Ethernet Controller
        Kernel driver in use: r8169
        Kernel modules: r8169
02:00.0 Network controller: Realtek Semiconductor Co., Ltd. RTL8723DE 802.11b/g/n PCIe Adapter
        Subsystem: Hewlett-Packard Company RTL8723DE 802.11b/g/n PCIe Adapter
        Kernel modules: rtw88_8723de
neevan@nebian:~$ sudo ip link
1: lo: <LOOPBACK,UP,LOWER_UP> mtu 65536 qdisc noqueue state UNKNOWN mode DEFAULT group default qlen 1000
    link/loopback 00:00:00:00:00:00 brd 00:00:00:00:00:00
2: eno1: <BROADCAST,MULTICAST,UP,LOWER_UP> mtu 1500 qdisc pfifo_fast state UP mode DEFAULT group default qlen 1000
    link/ether ea:7a:10:67:8b:af brd ff:ff:ff:ff:ff:ff
neevan@nebian:~$ nmcli dev
DEVICE  TYPE      STATE      CONNECTION         
eno1    ethernet  connected  Wired connection 1 
lo      loopback  unmanaged  --  
neevan@nebian:~$ sudo dmesg | grep -i wlan
[    3.266679] usb 1-4: Product: 802.11n WLAN Adapter
```

I have Windows 10 on dual boot and has no problems with WiFi there and I had Ubuntu 20.04LTS with GNOME before this Debian 10 installation and I had no WiFi problems then too. How do I install WiFi drivers and claim that device and use WiFi?

Comment: Try "apt install firmware-ralink". If no cigar, then try: "dmesg | grep -i ieee80211". Or see if you can find the chipset in the dmesg output.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Install the wifi driver from [lwfinger/rtw88](https://github.com/lwfinger/rtw88)  git repository:

```
sudo apt-get update
sudo apt-get install make gcc linux-headers-$(uname -r) build-essential git
git clone https://github.com/lwfinger/rtw88.git
cd rtw88
make
sudo make install
sudo modprobe -r rtw_8723de
sudo modprobe rtw_8723de
echo "options rtl8723de ant_sel=2" | sudo tee /etc/modprobe.d/rtl8723de.conf
```

The `ant_sel` may take `1`,`2`,`3` or `4` value.

Comment: this returned errors during first attempt.I tried again after a restart. worked like magic. thanks.

Comment: If the command `sudo modprobe rtw_8723de` output the error `Sudo modprobe rtw_8723de Modprobe: ERROR: could not insert rtw_8723de operation not permitted`. Disable secure boot in BIOS settings. See [Github issue](https://github.com/lwfinger/rtw88/issues/65)