# Not able to install realtek rtl8723de driver on debian 10.9

Tags: linux, debian, linux-kernel, wifi, selinux

I have recently installed debian 10.9 on my system using a non-free kde image. As expected there was no wifi so I had to configure it. I got this after running `lspci` , `03:00.0 Network controller: Realtek Semiconductor Co., Ltd. RTL8723DE 802.11b/g/n PCIe Adapter` . Then I found this ([Iwfinger/rtw88](https://github.com/lwfinger/rtw88)) driver through one of StackExchange's [Answers](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/394012/wifi-not-working-in-debian-8-9-having-rtl8723de-driver-10ecd723/394032#394032?newreg=1513c88a07124b60b6cdbaacf7bd5ece) by [@GAD3R](https://unix.stackexchange.com/users/153195/gad3r). I was following the steps mentioned by him as my kernel version is 4.19, until I hit this error: `modprobe: FATAL: Module rtw_8723de not found.`

Steps he mentioned:

```
sudo apt-get update
sudo apt-get install make gcc linux-headers-$(uname -r) build-essential git

git clone https://github.com/lwfinger/rtw88.git
cd rtw88
make
sudo make install

sudo modprobe -rv rtw_8723de 
sudo modprobe -v rtw_8723de
```

I think everything went well till `sudo make install`, and I got above mentioned error after running `sudo modprobe -rv rtw_8723de`.

I don't know what to do now, I really want to get wifi on my system, wired connection is unreliable for me.

I'll add the whole terminal log starting from the git clone command for better clarity.

```
chirag@debian10:~/Downloads$ git clone https://github.com/lwfinger/rtw88.git
Cloning into 'rtw88'...
remote: Enumerating objects: 481, done.
remote: Counting objects: 100% (481/481), done.
remote: Compressing objects: 100% (291/291), done.
remote: Total 481 (delta 324), reused 343 (delta 190), pack-reused 0
Receiving objects: 100% (481/481), 1.05 MiB | 2.73 MiB/s, done.
Resolving deltas: 100% (324/324), done.
```

```
chirag@debian10:~/Downloads$ cd rtw88
chirag@debian10:~/Downloads/rtw88$ make
make -C /lib/modules/4.19.0-16-amd64/build M=/home/chirag/Downloads/rtw88 modules
make[1]: Entering directory '/usr/src/linux-headers-4.19.0-16-amd64'


<<Note: I couldn't show this log here as most of it matches the later part and stackexchange won't let me keep it, as it thinks I am spamming>>


Building modules, stage 2.
  MODPOST 10 modules
  CC      /home/chirag/Downloads/rtw88/rtw_8723d.mod.o
  LD [M]  /home/chirag/Downloads/rtw88/rtw_8723d.ko
  CC      /home/chirag/Downloads/rtw88/rtw_8723de.mod.o
  LD [M]  /home/chirag/Downloads/rtw88/rtw_8723de.ko
  CC      /home/chirag/Downloads/rtw88/rtw_8821c.mod.o
  LD [M]  /home/chirag/Downloads/rtw88/rtw_8821c.ko
  CC      /home/chirag/Downloads/rtw88/rtw_8821ce.mod.o
  LD [M]  /home/chirag/Downloads/rtw88/rtw_8821ce.ko
  CC      /home/chirag/Downloads/rtw88/rtw_8822b.mod.o
  LD [M]  /home/chirag/Downloads/rtw88/rtw_8822b.ko
  CC      /home/chirag/Downloads/rtw88/rtw_8822be.mod.o
  LD [M]  /home/chirag/Downloads/rtw88/rtw_8822be.ko
  CC      /home/chirag/Downloads/rtw88/rtw_8822c.mod.o
  LD [M]  /home/chirag/Downloads/rtw88/rtw_8822c.ko
  CC      /home/chirag/Downloads/rtw88/rtw_8822ce.mod.o
  LD [M]  /home/chirag/Downloads/rtw88/rtw_8822ce.ko
  CC      /home/chirag/Downloads/rtw88/rtw_core.mod.o
  LD [M]  /home/chirag/Downloads/rtw88/rtw_core.ko
  CC      /home/chirag/Downloads/rtw88/rtw_pci.mod.o
  LD [M]  /home/chirag/Downloads/rtw88/rtw_pci.ko
make[1]: Leaving directory '/usr/src/linux-headers-4.19.0-16-amd64'
```

```
chirag@debian10:~/Downloads/rtw88$ sudo make install
make -C /lib/modules/4.19.0-16-amd64/build M=/home/chirag/Downloads/rtw88 modules
make[1]: Entering directory '/usr/src/linux-headers-4.19.0-16-amd64'
  Building modules, stage 2.
  MODPOST 10 modules
make[1]: Leaving directory '/usr/src/linux-headers-4.19.0-16-amd64'
Making backups
tar: /lib/modules/4.19.0-16-amd64/kernel/drivers/net/wireless/realtek/rtw88: Cannot stat: No such file or directory
tar: Exiting with failure status due to previous errors
make: *** [Makefile:83: install] Error 2
```

```
chirag@debian10:~/Downloads/rtw88$ sudo modprobe -rv rtw_8723de
modprobe: FATAL: Module rtw_8723de not found.
chirag@debian10:~/Downloads/rtw88$
```

Please also comment if need to add something more.

Comment: ... `Cannot stat: No such file or directory` suggests that `sudo make install` failed to install the module, thus the problem is not with modprobe--there is no installed mod for it to work on. Have you looked in to why it failed to install?

Comment: I don't what has caused this error, most of my system is updated. Do you know, what could be the possible reasons for install failure?

Comment: No, I do not. Please research that--Have you read the module's README file? Are you certain you have followed the build instructions (in the README)  correctly? I already see the README says something specific about your card, have you looked in to that?

Comment: I ran those commands again and this time it worked.

Comment: There appears to be something assumed in the install script which isn't always the case. Running 'sudo make install' twice worked for me.